# Flutter awesome_notification not showing notification while app is killed/closed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

My Push notification service is created by .net core and on flutter side I'm using awesome_notification to display notification. I can show notification while my app is running or in background. But can't see any notification while I killed/closed the app. How to show a notification while app is closed?(I'm not using firebase for push notification)

Comment: try with flutter_local_notifications

Comment: Midlaj Nazar, I've tried using flutter_local_notificaions. But same issue. Don't show any notification while app is closed. Would you provide some resource on this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@info.vikaasyadav/flutter-firebase-push-notification-2023-with-redirection-from-notification-fcm-e598c6c457d5